# How can I solve ,,PHP Warning: session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent"?

Tags: php, session

I have recently published my website on Hostgator and I have a problem with the sessions.
I have a session start on multiple pages: config.php, login.php, logout.php, index.php.

I have tried everything out there in with checking the whitespace, adding to the .httpaccess file, adding @ob_start()...and nothing seems to work.
In the error.log I have the following error:

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers
> already sent in ../config.php on line 3

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Session start should be placed at the top of the script. And don't repeat. To avoid errors, Just put a '@' before session_start command. Example

```
@session_start();
```

Comment: in newer php @ or surpression does not silence anymore

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `session_start()` at very beginning of scripts

config.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// do your other code here
```

in your subviews like index you should put the config.php in the very beginning of line or make a separate php file like `session.php` and include it on very beginning of scripts.

The cause of error is that session is trying to start but the page is already sent to the browser or rendered.

or maybe you have a whitespace in opening tag?

Comment: what do you mean by ,,in your subviews like index you should put the config.php in the very beginning of line ?"  How does making the session in another file help?

Comment: I mean you should create one file for that the include it of very beginning line of scripts

Comment: unfortunately, the error still persists but it says  ''PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in ..session.php on line 1" instead of saying that the error is in config.php

Comment: can you post the whole code here?